# Programmatically move items from web to master database?

Tags: sitecore-api

I have a utility page that creates Sitecore items from a csv file. This utility page is used to import thousands of items at a time, which are used for interactive map data. The items are stored in Year folders for organization. The import process starts by deleting all of the year folders, then programmatically creates new Year folders and items within those folders.

The issue is that if the upload fails due to a user trying to import bad data (say, an empty CSV file, or data that for some reason causes an error to be thrown), all of the items are deleted and do not get re-created.

The user can (and should) run the Export utility (which creates a CSV file of all the items, opposite of the Import) and/or make a Sitecore package as a backup in case of failure. However, I would like additional safety measures that don't depend on the user to remember to take backups, to restore the content if the import fails.

The items are deleted in the following method:

```
    private void DeleteAllTrialFolders(IMap_Page mapItem)
    {
        var folders = ItemService.GetDescendants(mapItem).OfType<IYear_Folder>();

        foreach (var folder in folders)
        {
            SitecoreService.Delete(folder);
        }
    }
```

Is there a way to transfer the root item and all children from web to master programmatically? Or another method of restoring items that have been deleted?

Comment: There is a SItecore Control panel application that can be used to move items from the Web database to the Master database. Have you looked at what that application is doing? Should be the Sitecore.Shell.Applications.Dialogs.TransferToDatabase.TransferToDatabaseForm class in the Sitecore.Client.dll

Comment: If a publish was not recently run, there is no guarantee that what's in the `web` db matches what was in the `master` db. So while you could transfer items, it probably makes more sense to rename the old root while importing and delete it on success, or else write an import process that does not need to delete everything up front.

Comment: Also worth noting that `item.Recycle()` can be used instead of `.Delete()` to move the item to the recycle bin. This makes it recoverable, but if a lot of imports are run it can also bloat the database.

Comment: You could change the "deletion" to use the recycle bin instead (`SitecoreService.ResolveItem(folder).Recycle()`), and then you'd have a place to go to restore the data.

Comment: Could you also not perform validation checks against the source before deleting items? Additionally, would it make more sense to create items in a "working" location that ensures the items can be created before deleting the original items, and then perform a MoveTo() of the root item to the needed location?  I'm thinking this is a procedural process issue, not a lack of available functionality in Sitecore.